# bash: adding a common string to files found with wildcards

Tags: bash, scp, wildcards

I'm wondering if there is a way to rename a wide range of files that are found using wildcard patterns.  For example, say I want to `scp` all files that match a certain pattern, but append a string to the filenames at a certain point.  Something like this:

**REMOTE:**

```
hello.txt
help.txt
heroes.txt
```

**I WANT LOCALLY:**

```
hello_copy.txt
help_copy.txt
heroes_copy.txt
```

Obviously `scp user@remote_host:~/he*.txt ./he*_copy.txt` doesn't work.  I'm wondering if this is possible, or if I need to copy every file individually.

Ideally I'm looking for a solution that works throughout bash, so that I could do the same thing with `mv`, `cp`, etc.

Comment: I'd probably copy the files to a local directory, the `mv` them out with the new name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately wildcards are quite limited. But it can be done with a couple extra commands. First, you can iterate through the files with a `for`:

```
bash$ ls -1
hello.txt
help.txt
heroes.txt
bash$ for f in *; do echo "$f"; done
hello.txt
help.txt
heroes.txt
```

You can also do an initial filtering using `*.txt` instead of just `*`. Make sure to quote the variable to prevent spaces or special characters in filenames from breaking the command.

Now you can **replace a string with another** with `sed` (the *backslash* is needed because the *dot* has a special meaning without it, and the *dollar sign* after it means "end of string"):

```
bash$ for f in *; do echo "$f" | sed s/\.txt$/_copy.txt/; done
hello_copy.txt
help_copy.txt
heroes_copy.txt
```

You can easily **transform this into a command**. For example an `mv` (let's see first how it looks doing an extra `echo`):

```
bash$ for f in *; do echo mv "$f" `echo "$f" | sed s/\.txt$/_copy.txt/`; done
mv hello.txt hello_copy.txt
mv help.txt help_copy.txt
mv heroes.txt heroes_copy.txt
```

Everything looks good so let's do it for real now:

```
bash$ for f in *; do mv "$f" `echo "$f" | sed s/\.txt$/_copy.txt/`; done
bash$ ls -1
hello_copy.txt
help_copy.txt
heroes_copy.txt
```

You can even **undo** the renaming using `sed s/_copy\.txt$/.txt/` :-)

Comment: You should put the command that does not break with spaces and special characters before the others rather than making it a special case. There are so many broken shell scripts around the Web already :)

Comment: You're right. Thanks for the edit :-)